# Comparing strings passed to function via char-pointers

Tags: c, function, pointers

I need help to compare two string on a functions using pointers, I know how to do this without using pointers.

Here is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

char *randString(int dif);
void compare(char *ptr, char *palabra[10]);
int main (){
    srand(time(NULL));

    int contador = 0;
    int dif;
    char *palabra[10];
    /*while (  contador < 100 ){
        char* ptr = randString();
        printf ( "%s\n", ptr );

        contador++;
    }*/
    printf("Dificultad: ");
    scanf("%i",&dif);
    char *ptr=randString(dif);
    printf("Palabra seleccionada: %s\n",ptr);

    printf("Introduce palabra para comparar: ");
    scanf("%s",palabra);

    compare( ptr, palabra );

    getchar();
    return 0;
}

static char difone[5][100] ={
    {"Duck"},
    {"Taxi"},
    {"Hola Mundo!"},
    {"Paris"},
    {"Lexugon"}
};
static char diftwo[5][100] ={
    {"colan"},
    {"cocuy"},
    {"cojee"},
    {"clona"},
    {"cobra"}
};
static char difthree[5][100] ={
    {"cogen"},
    {"codee"},
    {"cocio"},
    {"cogio"},
    {"coces"}
};

char *randString(int dif) {
    if(dif==1){
        return difone[rand() % ( 4 - 0 )] ;
    }else{
        if(dif==2){
            return diftwo[rand() % ( 4 - 0 )] ;
        }else{
            if(dif==3){
                return difthree[rand() % ( 4 - 0 )] ;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the compare function:

```
void compare(char* ptr, char *palabra[10]){
    printf("Palabra seleccionada: %s\n",ptr);
    printf("Palabra introducida: %s",palabra);

    if(strcmp((*ptr)[1],(*palabra)[1]==0){
        printf("Igual");
    }else{
        printf("No igual");
    }

}
```

Comment: 1) `scanf("%s",palabra);` is wrong. because `palabra` is a `char**` while `%s` expects a `char*`. 2) Your `randString()` function doesn't return anything if `dif` is not 1,2 or 3.     3)All `rand() % ( 4 - 0 )` should be `rand()%5`. 4)`void compare(char* ptr, char *palabra[10])` should be `void compare(char* ptr, char **palabra)` 5)`if(strcmp((*ptr)[1],(*palabra)[1]==0)` doesn't make any sense and is wrong

Comment: See (`-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` for gcc), read and and take your compiler's warnings serious. Fix them (without wildly casting around) and the chances your code works better are higher.

Comment: i am so sorry for this code but just i want to make a fast resume this is the reason for this so many warnings ... thanks to this i got the problem now is solved it was the pointer....

Answer (score 1):

So, several issues:

First, you declare `palabra` as an *array of pointer to `char`*, which is not what you want based on the code:

```
  scanf("%s",palabra);
```

If you want `palabra` to store a single string of 9 characters or less, simply declare it as

```
char palabra[10];
```

This means you'll also need to change the declaration and definition of your `compare` function, like so:

```
void compare( char *ptr, char *palabra )
```

Next, change your `strcmp` call in the `compare` function to

```
if( strcmp( ptr, palabra ) ==0 ){
```

The expression `(*ptr)[1]` attempts to dereference `ptr` and then apply the subscript to the result, which is *not* going to work in this case.  The result of `*ptr` is the value of the first character in the string `ptr` points to (one of the strings in your `difone`, `diftwo`, and `difthree` arrays).  A single character is not an array or pointer expression, so you can't apply the `[]` operator to it.

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, an array expression like `palabra` will be converted ("decay") to a pointer expression, and the value of the pointer will be the address of the first element of the array.  We declare `palabra` as a 10-element array of `char` in `main`, but when we pass it as an argument to `scanf` or `compare`, that array expression is converted to a pointer expression, which is why we declare it as `char *palabra` in the definition to `compare`.